# Update partial Date time column value in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to update date time column in my SQL server.Consider the date time column contains following values,

```
2015-02-13 00:00:00.000
2015-02-18 00:00:00.001
2015-02-21 00:05:00.002
2015-02-13 00:03:00.003
2015-02-19 01:00:00.004
2015-01-13 00:00:00.005
2015-01-11 00:01:00.006
2015-01-13 00:02:00.007
```

I want to change the only the day to 14 without making any change in other values(year,month,time). Could you please help me to write a update statement for this?

Comment: This table is predefined by the client. i can't make change in this

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your where conditions you can use DATEADD function, like `DATEADD(day, 1, column)`. This will not affect other parts.

If the day parts differ, you can use

```
column = DATEADD(day, 14-DATEPART(day, column), column)
```

Comment: I can't use this DATEADD function for other dates like '2014-09-24 00:00:00.000'. Here the day ,month and time is changing. I have to update 1000+ records.

Comment: @Bibin so every value should have the day changed, but year and time as previously?

Comment: yes. Day should be changed 14 , but year and time should be the same as the previously

Answer (score 0):

want to update only specify date with out affecting HH:MM:SS then in filter condition use Substring also 
Assume your table like this :

```
update table 
set datecol = DATEADD(DAY,1,DATECOL) 
where 
datecol = SUBSTRING(DATECOL,0,CHARINDEX(' ',DATECOL))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 
set column1 = dateadd(dd,14, convert(datetme, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(column1)-1),column),101),112))
```